# Cannot modify prototype properties of a constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, properties, prototype

Newbie over here. Playing around with constructors and instanced objects (and how you can modify the prototype properties of a constructor to affect all of its instanced objects), I tried the following:

```js
function Bird() {
  this.name = "Albert";
  this.color = "blue";
  this.eyes = 2;
};

Bird.prototype.numLegs = 2;

let blueBird = new Bird();
let redBird = new Bird();

console.log(blueBird); // output: Bird { name: 'Albert', color: 'blue', eyes: 2 }
console.log(redBird); // output: Bird { name: 'Albert', color: 'blue', eyes: 2 }
```

Am I missing something? Shouldn't blueBird and redBird have the numLegs property and have its value set to 2?

Comment: Your code works fine. `numLegs` does exist on `Bird.prototye`, which instances inherit from.

Comment: Prototype properties don't show up when you log an object, only the object's own properties.

Comment: If you do `console.log(blueBird.numLegs)` you'll see it.